# ASP.NET How to receive HTTP data from Android app using OkHttp

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, vb.net

I am learning android and `webservices`. I have an android application that sends data using `okHttp` and I need to ingest that data on my server and put it into the database. I have a little experience calling and getting data from `webservices` but have never received data.

As I understand it, in ASP.Net I will need to use a `HttpHandler` and I have seen some examples but they always seem to be returning data per the request. How do you keep the `HttpHandler` always listening for this particular incoming data?

Here is the code from my sample android application.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView outputText;
Button sendData;
EditText edtUser, edtPass;
final String URL = "http://serviceapi.skholingua.com/open-feeds/display_received_params.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    outputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    sendData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    edtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    sendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userName = edtUser.getText().toString();
            String passWord = edtPass.getText().toString();
            OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(userName, passWord);
            String result = null;
            try {
                result = handler.execute(URL).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outputText.append(result + "\n");
        }
    });
}
```

The Class

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String userName, passWord;

public OkHttpHandler(String userName, String passWord) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.userName = userName;
    this.passWord = passWord;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("name", userName)
            .add("pass", passWord)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(params[0]).post(formBody)
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful())
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response.toString());
        return response.body().string();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

The `URL` will be changed to whatever I create on my server. My question is.. What type of data will this be sending? What do I need to create on my server to ingest it?
If anyone has an example that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Web API.

Example to read a POST to address hxxp://yourdomain/test/[variable]/[variable] and GET to address hxxp://yourdomain/test/[id]. For example:

```
hxxp://yourdomain/test2/1 will return the string "You requested number 1"

hxxp://yourdomain/test2/2 will return the string "You requested number 2"
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController {    
    [Route("test/{username}/{password}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public string Post(string username, string password) {  
        if(username == "user" && password == "pass") {  // check user/pass
             string data = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             //do something
             return "User is authenticated";
        }
    }

    [Route("test2/{id}")] {
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public string GetData(int id) { 
        return "You requested number " + id;
    }
}
```

In your example above you would call:

```
hxxp://yourdomain/test/name/pass
```

And get the response "User is authenticated"

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the help..I am looking into Web API now but still confused... Can you please elaborate on what your example above is? Looking up Web API I find tons of examples about how to get data from a web service but not much on how to listen for data posting to your service.